# Unpredictable crash due to UIView animations

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have made a custom activity indicator to use in a project. I rotate a static loader image for that.

```
- (void) rotate {
    lastInstance++;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(rotate)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    spinnerImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI*(lastInstance%10)/5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The `spinnerimageview` is contained within a superview container, and it bears the static loader image. It works fine, except for crashing unpredictably without any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're stuck in a never ending recursion. How do you decide when to stop the rotation?

Each time the rotation animation completes it simply calls `rotate` again, with seemingly no end in sight.

The crash you are seeing is likely a stack overflow (how apt).

I'd suggest rethinking how to you decide whether the animation could continue.

Comment: yes...it keeps on rotating indefinitely, i just show and hide it when needed

Comment: Then that's almost surely what's happening. You'll need to rewrite so that you're not infinitely recursing. I'd suggest using a timer which repeatedly triggers the rotate method as opposed to using the animation delegate to recall the same method it's in.

Comment: The timer is good advice. Also, do not set the delegate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794562/sigsegv-segv-accerr-crash-reports-what-to-do/17184663#17184663  then when implementing the NSTimer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098146/what-caused-this-iphone-crash-log/17202550#17202550